# jQuery AutoComplete using breeze as the datasource

Tags: knockout.js, autocomplete, breeze

I am trying to build a single page app (SPA) using durandal, knockout and breeze.  I was wondering if anyone had a good example they would like to share showing how to use a jQuery AutoComplete with breeze as the data source.  I would not want to load all the possible choices upfront.  Instead as the user is typing I want to be generating breeze queries in the background and populating the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found this JSFiddle that I should be able to get working.